Evans - existence of parabolic PDE, why does $B(u_m,v)\to B(u,v)$?
In Evans book, chapter 7.1, he establishes existence of weak solutions of
$$\partial_t u + Lu = f$$
where $L$ is a uniformly elliptic differential operator.
He first shows that for any $m$, the Galerkin approximation
$$u_m(t)=\sum_{k=1}^m d_k(t) w_k$$
exists, i.e. that we can find the coefficients $d_k(t)$ s.t. $u_m$ solves the weak problem
$$\langle u_m', v \rangle_{H^{-1}} + B(u_m,v) = (f,v)\quad\forall v\in H^1_0,$$
where $B(u,v):=\int_\Omega \nabla u^\intercal A \nabla v + (b\cdot\nabla u) v + cuv dx$ and where $w_k$ are basis functions of $H^1_0$.
Then we find apriori energy estimates, i.e. the sequences
$$(u_m)\subset L^2(0,T;H^1_0), \quad (u'_m)\subset L^2(0,T;H^{-1})$$
are bounded by initial conditions and by the RHS $f$.
The Banach-Alaoglu Theorem implies existence of weakly converging subsequences (denoted by $u_m$ as well). I understand that weak convergence on a Hilbert space means convergence in the inner product of that space. So e.g. for $(u_m)_m$, we know that
$$(u_m, v)_{L^2(H^1_0)} \to (u,v)_{L^2(H^1_0)}\quad\forall v\in H^1_0$$
which means
$$\int _0^T \int_\Omega u_m v dxdt + \int _0^T \int_\Omega \nabla u_m \cdot\nabla v dxdt \to \int _0^T \int_\Omega u v dxdt + \int _0^T \int_\Omega \nabla u \cdot\nabla v dxdt \quad\forall v\in H^1_0.$$
What I dont get:
It is claimed, the previous results imply that
$$\int_0^T \langle u'_m, v\rangle + B(u_m,v) dt = \int_0^T (f,v) dt$$
converges to
$$\int_0^T \langle u', v\rangle + B(u,v) dt = \int_0^T (f,v) dt.$$
But I dont get why

$\langle u'_m, v\rangle \to \langle u', v\rangle\quad\forall v$
$\int_0^T  B(u_m,v) \to \int_0^T  B(u,v)\quad\forall v$

as neither $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$, nor $B(\cdot,\cdot)$ are the canonical inner products on our Hilbert spaces.

You could use ibp for part 1

Is it correct that you suggest to use $\langle u'_m,v\rangle = - \langle u_m,v'\rangle \to -\langle u,v'\rangle = \langle u',v\rangle$? If so, isn't it necessary that $u'\in L^2$ for that?

That should follow from the fact that $u_t$ exists

Ok, so: $\langle u'm,v\rangle = - \langle u_m,v'\rangle =-(u_m,v'){L^2}  \to -(u,v')_{L^2}= -\langle u,v'\rangle = \langle u',v\rangle$, as both $u_m,v'\in L^2$, correct? Do you also know why the bilinearform $B$ converges (question 2)?

Q1)
see comment under main post
Q2)
The answer is given here: Weak convergence in Sobolev spaces involving time

Evans assumes the bilinearform $B$ is bounded, i.e. $B(u,v)\leq\Vert u\Vert \Vert v\Vert$
The map $u\mapsto B(u,v)$ is a linear functional
by definition of weak convergence, this functional preserves convergence

